# How to specify the Docker context when using docker-plugin for Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins

When i try to make a build in Jenkins I get the following error:

> Could not build image: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat requirements.txt: file does not exist

I believe that's because of the Dockerfile's location. This is my folder structure:

[image]

I'm using the docker-plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin), in Jenkins. When I'm setting the job there's a textbox 'Build Args', where i think it might be the right place to set the context to the root of the project, but i cannot understand what should i put there (if this is the right place to).

When building without Jenkins, i just enter the command and it succeed:

```
docker build -f conf/env/docker/Dockerfile -t company/project:tag .
```

In the 'Build Args' text box I tried to put '.', './', but the hint says that should be something like "key=value".